# Development Storage Account Requires Authentication

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-table-storage

I am using a CloudTableClient to access Table storage:

```
private StorageCredentials credentials;
public StorageCredentials StorageAccount
{
   get
   {
       if (credentials == null)
       {
           credentials = new StorageCredentials(config["AzureStorageSettings:AccountName"],
                                                 config["AzureStorageSettings:AccountKey"]);
       }

       return credentials;
   }
}

public CloudTableClient Tableclient
{
    get
    {
        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(StorageAccount, true);
        return storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    }
 }

 public string TableReference => config["CampaignStorageName"];
```

with the settings:

```
"AzureStorageSettings:AccountName": "devstoreaccount1",
"AzureStorageSettings:AccountKey": "Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==",
```

but every time I try to retrieve a record from the table

```
public IngestionEntity GetIngestionRecord(IngestionMessage msg)
{
    var table = Tableclient.GetTableReference(TableReference);
    var retrieve = TableOperation.Retrieve<IngestionEntity>(msg.PartitionKey, msg.RowKey);

    var result = table.Execute(retrieve);

    log.LogInformation($"{msg.ToString()}, " +
           $"Query Status Code: {result.HttpStatusCode}, " +
           $"Cost: {result.RequestCharge}");

    return (IngestionEntity)result.Result;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
```

I am assuming this is related to https v http which dev storage uses but is there a way to allow this to authenticate so that I can use the TableClient as above or should I be doing this differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
private CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
public CloudStorageAccount StorageAccount
{
    get
    {
        if (storageAccount == null)
        {
            storageAccount = config["AzureStorageSettings:AccountName"] == "devstoreaccount1" ? CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount : new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(config["AzureStorageSettings:AccountName"], config["AzureStorageSettings:AccountKey"]), true);
        }

        return storageAccount;
    }
}

public CloudTableClient Tableclient
{
    get
    {
        return StorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    }
}
```

Basically Storage Emulator has different endpoints than your regular Storage Accounts and when you create an instance of `CloudStorageAccount` using Storage Emulator credentials, the SDK thinks that you're trying to connect to an account named `devstoreaccount1` in the cloud. Because the key for `devstoreaccount1` is not the same as the key for Storage Emulator account, you're getting 403 error.

Comment: Same outcome with that but I take the point and I will see what I can get like that. If I check the credentials there is no SAS or signature.

Comment: tried this    credentials = config["ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"] == "Development" after changing the other settings back and it is set up correctly with dev credentials but still produces the error

Comment: I made a mistake, sorry about that! Updated my answer. Actually you would need to change your `StorageAccount` property so that it's of type `CloudStorageAccount` instead of `StorageCredentials`.

Comment: Excellent thank you. I had to default the private CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = null; as it does not appear to be null by default. I also changed to use the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT config value to achieve what I was after but it now retrieves from dev storage

Comment: Awesome! I am glad to hear that you're unblocked.